# Odds of Winning a Scratch Card

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, dice

I have a scratch card that has 36 spaces that can be scratch.  9 of the spaces have a winning symbol and 27 spaces have an "X".  I am allowed to scratch as many spaces until I either get the 9 winning symbols or 3 "X's".  What are the odds that I will successfully scratch the 9 winning symbols before getting 3 "X's"?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It is useful to when asking a question to include your thoughts on the problem including what you have tried, and where you are stuck. This better enables other users to give you the feedback you require, and deliver an answer appropriate to your level of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You may imagine that even if you win, you continue scratching until you have scratched a total of nine wins and two $x$'s.  You may also temporarily assume that each space is numbered.

In other words, consider a win as getting exactly nine winning spaces and two X's.  It should be clear that any win under the normal rules corresponds to a win using these rules and vice versa.

Consider our sample space as all ways of scratching eleven spaces where order matters.  Our winning event in question is the set of ways of scratching eleven spaces where nine of the spaces are good where order matters.

What is the size of the sample space?

> $\frac{36!}{(36-11)!} = \frac{36!}{25!} = P(36,11) = ~_{36}P_{11}=36^{\underline{11}}$ depending on your preferred notation.  I'll continue by using $\frac{36!}{25!}$

What is the size of the event that you win?

> Pick which of the winning spaces you used where order doesn't matter (One way of accomplishing this).  Pick which of the X spaces you used where order doesn't matter ($\binom{27}{2}=~_{27}C_2=C(27,2)=\frac{27!}{2!25!}$ ways of doing this).  Pick the order that the chosen spaces occur:  ($11!$).  Applying multiplication principle, there are $\binom{27}{2}11!$ ways in which you win.

The sample space is clear to see is unbiased, so we may use that the probability of the event occuring as the size of the event divided by the size of the sample space.

---

Note: Alternatively, we could have set the sample space as the number of ways in which we pick eleven spaces where order *doesn't* matter, which is also an unbiased sample space.  In this case, we count the number of ways to win where order of selection doesn't matter.

This will give the same result, either way.

> Both simplify as $\frac{\binom{27}{2}}{\binom{36}{11}}$

Comment: I follow that logic and therefore i get a probability of .00000058 but if I changed the scenario to 45 spaces and there are only 6 correct spaces and 39 X's and again that person can scratch till they get 3 X's or all the correct 6 spaces then the probability calculates to .000003437.  That implies the person has better odds with this second scenario than with the first scenario.  That doesn't seem right but according to the formula it is.  Am i missing something?

Comment: @Gary I calculate the probability of the original scenario to be $\frac{\binom{27}{2}}{\binom{36}{11}}\approx 5.84\cdot 10^{-7}$, and the probability of the second scenario to be $\frac{\binom{33}{2}}{\binom{39}{8}}\approx 8.58\cdot 10^{-6}$, so your math was off a bit for the second scenario.  Yes, the person will have better odds in the second scenario.  He needs a shorter string of successes, and although each individual success is less likely, since the number of necessary successes is less the math works out this way.

Comment: @Gary Imagine taking this to the extreme, where there is only one winning space out of fifty or whatever and he has one chance to find it.  It is less likely for him to find this winning space than it would have been for him to find a winning space in the original scenario in a single attempt, but if he succeeds then he has won the prize.  Finding one space out of fifty in a single attempt occurs with probability $0.02$, which is *much* higher than that of the original question.